# High chart partial rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

not sure why, but when the page is rendered for the first time the high chart renders partially, as soon as i resize the page or open dev tools it renders properly. that behavior is common all across the browsers. could anyone advice a way to solve that minor but annoying problem. thanks in advance.

Highstock JS v2.1.10 (2015-12-07)
Highcharts JS v4.1.10 (2015-12-07)

[image]

Comment: When highcharts resizes it triggers a 'redraw' event. Maybe try calling this on load to see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: @MichaelCurry thanks, i'll try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, shout-out to @MichaelCurry whose suggestion helped me to get rid of this annoying issue, wanna leave this piece of code here, might be helpful to someone else

```
// that helps to avoid partial rendering of the high chart
setTimeout(function () {
    self.chart.redraw();
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem and I just upgrade highcharts version to 5.0.12 to fix this.